# Pythonping not working with a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, ip, ping

I want to make it so that this discord bot can ping,portscan and whois Servers and IPs.All of the commands work perfectly fine but when I try to use pythonping i get a error which i can't see.i get this message in discord, `<coroutine object Command.call at 0x04E55368>` and this error in the Visual Studio Code terminal i get this error, `C:\Users\swevl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py:85: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`.

Here is my code:

````
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import random
import string
import time
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import string
from os import system, name
import aiohttp
from pythonping import ping
import requests

# # # # # # # # # # Bot Config and Token # # # # # # # # # #
def clear():
  
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')
  
    else:
        _ = system('clear')

clear()
os.system("cls && title Gen Bot")
token = "Censored Bot Token"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='a!', case_insensitive=True)
client.remove_command('help')
print(f"                 {Fore.RED}╔═╗╦  ╔═╗╦ ╦╔═╗  ╔╗ ╔═╗╔╦╗")
print(f"                 {Fore.RED}╠═╣║  ╠═╝╠═╣╠═╣  ╠╩╗║ ║ ║ ")
print(f"                 {Fore.RED}╩ ╩╩═╝╩  ╩ ╩╩ ╩  ╚═╝╚═╝ ╩ ")
print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}I-----------------------------------------------------I")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # login of client
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name='a!help'))
    print(f"{Fore.RED}[{Fore.YELLOW}STATUS{Fore.RED}] The bot just went online!".format(client))
#####Utiity Commands#####
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send("Messages have been removed!", delete_after=4)
    print (f'{Fore.RED}[{Fore.YELLOW}LOGS{Fore.RED}] {ctx.author} cleared {amount} messages')



#########################################################################################################################################





@client.command(name='whois')
async def whois(ctx, arg1):
   if arg1 == "":
       await ctx.send("Invalid IP!")
   else:
       async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(f"http://ip-api.com/json/{arg1}?fields=66846719") as r:
                    js = await r.json()
                    myip = ('')
                    if myip == (js["query"]):
                        await ctx.send('Invalid Ip!')
                    else:
                        cont = (js["continent"])
                        country = (js["country"])
                        region = (js["regionName"])
                        city = (js["city"])
                        zipcode = (js["zip"])
                        iso = (js["isp"])
                        org = (js["org"])
                        reverse = (js["reverse"])
                        mobile = (js["mobile"])
                        proxy = (js["proxy"])
                        hosting = (js["hosting"])
                        embed1 = discord.Embed(title=(js["query"]), color = discord.Color.red())
                        embed1.add_field(name="info", value=(f"{ctx.author.mention}\n"
                                                                         f"Continent: {cont} \n"
                                                                         f"country: {country} \n"
                                                                         f"Region: {region}\n"
                                                                         f"City: {city} \n"
                                                                         f"Zip: {zipcode} \n"
                                                                         f"ISP: {iso} \n"
                                                                         f"Org: {org} \n"
                                                                         f"Reverse: {reverse} \n"
                                                                         f"Mobile: {mobile} \n"
                                                                         f"Proxy: {proxy} \n"
                                                                         f"Hosting: {hosting}"), inline=False)
                        await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
                        print (f'{Fore.RED}[{Fore.YELLOW}LOGS{Fore.RED}] {ctx.author} used the whois comand on {arg1}')




@client.command()
async def portscan(ctx, arg1):
    if arg1 == '':
     await ctx.send("Invalid IP!")
    else:
       print (f'{Fore.RED}[{Fore.YELLOW}LOGS{Fore.RED}] {ctx.author} portscanned {arg1}')
       async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(f"https://api.hackertarget.com/nmap/?q={arg1}") as r:
                       if r.status == 200:
                        text = await r.text()
                        embed1 = discord.Embed(title=(f'Results from {arg1}'), description=(text), color = discord.Color.red())
                        await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
                       else:
                               await ctx.send("API is offline, try again later...")


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, arg1):
        if arg1 == '':
                await ctx.send("Invalid IP!")
        else:
                await ctx.send(ping(arg1))





client.run(token)```
````

Comment: Can you show me where in my code this error is?

Answer (score 0):

i use this code to find the bot ping

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Bot ping",
                          description=f"{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms",
                          color=discord.Colour.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can walk you through the error from your code:

```py
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, arg1):
        if arg1 == '':
                await ctx.send("Invalid IP!")
        else:
                await ctx.send(ping(arg1))
```

When you hit the **else** statement, you call the ping function again. You never awaited the ping function (it is a coro), which is why the error is being raised. From what you provided here, it seems this command would do nothing but eventually crash your discord bot. It would keep calling itself over and over again (infinite recursion).

What I think you're trying to do is have a command that pings an ip and returns a response. You need to use a different function to ping, you can't call the same one over and over again.

```py
async def ping_ip(ip) -> str:  # The function returns a string
    ... # Do pinging here and return a str

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, ip: str):
    data = await ping_ip(ip)
    return await ctx.send(data)
```

Comment: I changed it now it gives me this message "<class 'str'>"
It doesn't give any syntax error.
Here is my code:
`async def ping_ip(ip) -> str:  # The function returns a string
    ping
    return str # Do pinging here and return a str

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, ip: str):
    data = await ping_ip(ip)
    return await ctx.send(data)
client.run(token)`